# Smallest subalgebra of $\mathfrak{su}(4)$ arrising from a control problem on $SU(4)$

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, lie-algebras

What is the smallest subalgebra of $\mathfrak{su}(4)$ containing the span of the set $A = \{A, B_1, B_2\}$ where:

$A = i (J^x \sigma_x \otimes \sigma_x + J^y \sigma_y \otimes \sigma_y + J^z \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z)$ for some real numbers $J^k$ and

$B_1 = i\sigma_z \otimes I$ and
$B_2 = I \otimes \sigma_z$.

NB:  In the above definitions, $\sigma_x$, $\sigma_y$, and $\sigma_z$ are the Pauli matrices, $P\otimes Q$ means the Kronecker product of matrices, and the constants $J^x$, $J^y$, and $J^z$ are fixed but arbitrary.

Comment: The $\sigma$s are the Paul matrices and the others are defined by me in the question.

Comment: Physically $A$ is the heisenberg spin chain Hamiltonian and the $B$ r represent the effect of an external magnetic field.

Comment: It is the kronecker product of matrices In coordinates.

Comment: The $J^k$s are all fixed and represent the strength of the spin-spin coupling of two "sites" in the spin chain. The physical meaning is not so relevant here though, so yes the $J^k$s are fixed and arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks for the definitions.  I went ahead and added them to your question so that it would be clearer to readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on the values of the constants $J^x$, $J^y$, and $J^z$.  Here is what direct computation yields:

If $J^x=J^y=J^z=0$, so that $A=0$, then $B_1$ and $B_2$ span a $2$-dimensional abelian subalgebra.

If $J^x=J^y=0$, but $J^z\not=0$, then $A$, $B_1$, and $B_2$ span a $3$-dimensional abelian subalgebra (i.e., a maximal torus in ${\frak{su}}(4)$.

If $J^x = \pm J^y \not = 0$ and $J^z=0$, then they generate a $4$-dimensional subalgebra isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}\oplus {\frak{su}}(2)$.

If $J^x = \pm J^y \not = 0$ and $J^z\not=0$, then they generate a $5$-dimensional subalgebra isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R}\oplus {\frak{su}}(2)$.

If $J^x \not= \pm J^y $ and $J^z=0$, then they generate a $6$-dimensional subalgebra isomorphic to ${\frak{su}}(2)\oplus {\frak{su}}(2)$.

If $J^x \not= \pm J^y $ and $J^z\not=0$, then they generate a $7$-dimensional subalgebra isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}\oplus {\frak{su}}(2)\oplus {\frak{su}}(2)$.

All of these follow by direct computation with matrices, which is made easier, when you write them out, by interchanging the second and fourth columns and rows, because then everything is conjugated into the Lie subalgebra of $S\bigl(SU(2)\times SU(2)\bigr)$.